# Are ppr pipes not worth the money?

Tags: plumbing

I installed PPR pipes in my house for water supply and now after investing so much of money and time a person today told me that plastic pipes are not good enough as they burst in freezing temperatures( we live in freezing temperatures and normally it dips 5 degrees Celsius below zero in winters).  And also said that if hot water from a geyser(a water boiler) passes through them then the water stinks of the plastic!

From listening to this I'm very anxious and depressed. Has the money been wasted?
I've added a picture which has the details written on it, the right one is more detailed.
Any help is appreciated.
God bless you.[image]

Comment: Any pipe material can fail if it freezes....

Comment: *we live in freezing temperatures and normally it dips 5 degrees Celsius below zero in winters* Key question: Does it ever (barring an unusual crisis like an extended power failure) ever get below 0 degrees Celsius **in any rooms where the pipes are installed**? If the rooms with the pipes are 20 C (or even 5 C) then it doesn't matter if it is is -20 C outside. According to the Prince web site, the pipes are good for -20 to 95, though personally I would be concerned once you get below 0 - freezing is never good for pipes.

Comment: @Dear manassehkatz few pipes go out of the house  where it may dip below freezing

Comment: Did you protect the pipes outside from UV and temperature ie covered and / or insilation?

Comment: @Solar Mike, no I did not cover them from outside.

Comment: So, you should consider doing that.

Comment: The only place I use PPE is for air lines, the layers prevent fractures and the pipe from blowing apart. The best time to ask this type of question is prior to using, you may have spent more than needed but not a total waste. I would put insulation on the pipes that are exposed to the -5C being at 0 damage usually not occur it takes -3 or lower for 4 hours for pipes to break up adding insulation you extend the safe range to prove this to yourself take a section of pipe fill with water and put in your freezer you will see it normally takes 3-4 hours for the water to freeze.

Comment: @Ed Beal Thanks a lot dear, I'll try the freezer method, and see. Thank you again for this nice idea!

Comment: @Solar Mike, Thank you I'll insulate the pipes.

Comment: How close to a geyser do you live that there's a possibility of one erupting through your plumbing? On a more serious note, if you don't smell the plastic when you run hot water now, it's not likely that you will in the future. Also, congrats on including a nice, clear, readable pic in your OP without having to be prompted! It's amazing how many people don't do that...

Comment: @EdBeal The OP & the pic clearly show `PPR` on the pipe, but you mention `PPE`. Are those different pipe types or was that a typo on your part?

Comment: I think spell check changed it I did not notice. Yup it just did it again ppr being multi layer doesn’t shatter as easily as pvc, @freeman.

Comment: Just checkin', @EdBeal. All this high tech stuff is so very helpful _when it works right_...

Comment: What does a geyser have do to with this?  I'm guessing this is a translation error.  In the US, a geyser is a geological structure that regularly erupts hot water (like Old Faithful at Yellowstone NP).

Comment: @George Anderson,  I meant a water boiler by geyser, I've edited the question. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: You may have spent more on this type of piping than was absolutely necessary, but you'll spend far more if you rip it out and replace it with something cheaper! Insulate the outdoor plumbing (as others recommended) and move on.

Answer (score 2):

### I'd insulate the pipes and move on

PPR, like PEX and unlike PVC, is a freeze-tolerant material; however, that doesn't mean that pipes made from it should be allowed to freeze on a routine basis.  I would start by adding pipe insulation (foam pipe insulation is available as prefab, "peel and stick" pieces) provided these are not irrigation pipes, which should be drained/blown out for the winter season anyway.  I am baffled as to how you wound up with plumbing runs on the outside of your house, though...